# Why Pull To Refresh do not stop after two refresh

Tags: android, android-listview

I set [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library. Below my code. When i refresh first time, all work good, but if i refresh second time and more, refresh is do not stop. How fix it?

```
PullToRefreshListView pullToRefreshView;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    pullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_listview);
    pullToRefreshView.setMode(Mode.BOTH);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    pullToRefreshView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener2<ListView>() {
        @Override
        public void onPullDownToRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            list.add("Item down =-=");
            refreshView.onRefreshComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPullUpToRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            list.add("Item up =-=");
            refreshView.onRefreshComplete();
        }
    });

}
```